# submit a form from radiobutton using ajax

Tags: ajax, yii

how do i submit a form through a radio button without refreshing the page?

This submits by refreshing the entire page

```
<?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'yesno',
    array('Y'=>"<img src=\"".Yii::app()->baseUrl."/images/site/yes.png\" id=\"yes-i\"/> ",
    'N'=>"<img src=\"".Yii::app()->baseUrl."/images/site/no.png\" id=\"no-i\"/>"),array(
    'class'=>'fire-toggle','labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline'),
    'separator'=>'  ',
    'onclick'=>Chtml::ajax(array(
        'success'=>"$('#yesno-form').submit()")))); //This doesn't work.. 
?>
```

Comment: HOLY MOLEY, there is almost a time where CHtml and FomrUI makes no more sence ^^. HTML please!

Answer (score 0):

Update your onclick as follows,

```
'onclick' => 'js: function(){$.post(\'<url>\', $(\'#<form-id>\').serialize(), function(data){alert(data)})}'
```

set the  and  appropriately